# JQuery get selected value from selected dropdowns and add to total

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How would I begin, I would like to select the value enclosed in "[]" of each of the selected and add it to #theFinalPrice?

```
<div ID="theFinalPrice">$20.00</div>

<p>Hotel:<br />
<select name="variation1" class="eStore_variation">
<option value="King Bed [+ $50.00]">King Bed</option>
<option value="Double Bed">Double Bed</option>
</select></p>

<p>Add a Guest:<br />
<select name="variation2" class="eStore_variation">
<option value="no added guests">no added guests</option>
<option value="+1 guest [+ $35.00]">+1 guest [+ $35.00]</option>
</select></p>

<p>Additional Fun:<br />
<select name="variation3" class="eStore_variation">
<option value="no additional fun">no additional fun</option>
<option value="1 game of golf [+ $35.00]">+1 game of golf [+ $35.00]</option>
</select></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In whatever change or click handler you'd like, you can use jQuery's `each` to get and sum all the values:

```
var total = 0; // Set to some base price

$('.eStore_variation option:selected').each(function() {
    var m = /\[\+ \$(\d+\.\d+)\]/.exec(this.value);

    if(m !== null) {
        total += +m[1];
    }
});

var decimalPart = (total - Math.floor(total)) * 100;

$('#theFinalPrice').text('$' + Math.floor(total) + '.' + (decimalPart < 10 ? '0' : '') + decimalPart);
```

[Here's a demo jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/gQexk/)

Comment: WOW!  thank you!  You didn't have to write it for me :) I'm learning JS and I like it more and more.  Anyway, when there's a price not attached, it enters a "0" for the price.  Anyway to stop this?

Comment: @user1040259: Just set the `var total = 0;` to whatever your base price is. (`20.00`?) Also... you're welcome! :)

Comment: Can I ask one more question?  What if I wanted to use this JS code for several different product pages, each having a different total price.  Can I do something like this - var total = $("#theFinalPrice").text().replace(/[$]/, "");

Comment: @user1040259: Just make it into a function that takes `total` as an argument and returns the result instead of calling `$('#theFinalPrice').text()` with it. Then, call that function in each place it's needed.

Comment: sorry, can you give an example?

Comment: @user1040259: Sure; see https://gist.github.com/3056162 for the function. In this particular case, for example, you'd call it like: `$('#theFinalPrice').text(calculateTotal($('.eStore_variation'), 20.00))`, where the first argument to `calculateTotal` is the boxes for which to calculate totals and the second argument is the base price.

Comment: why couldn't it just be this simple?   var total = /\[\+ \$(\d+\.\d+)\]/.exec($("#theFinalPrice").value);